# What is the Correlation between the shadow/s of the gap and the dark regions in a double-slit-experiment?

Tags: double-slit-experiment

Are the destructive interference dark areas on the wall behind the slits also the shadow of barrier between the slits?

Or the shadow is only a triangle which its base is the barrier and its tip somewhere closer to the slits than to the wall?

Comment: I don't know what you are asking.   What do you mean by "on the wall behind the slits"?  Can you include a sketch?

Comment: @garyp On the screen where we can see the interference pattern NOT the opposite side of the slits

Comment: See if this helps: https://commons.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Interference_electrons_double-slit_at_10cm.png

Comment: Do you think that the diffraction pattern looks like a shadow of the barrier?   Actually there is no shadow at all unless you are very close to the slits.   A diffraction pattern is not a shadow.

Comment: @safesphere yes it helps. Does that mean there is no shadow is completely eliminated before the screen?

Comment: On a bright sunny day you close curtains and your room becomes dark. It is in a shadow now. Then you cut two tiny slits in the curtain. Is the shadow eliminated? Not really. Your room is still mostly dark. You just need to think through carefully what exactly you mean by shadow.

Comment: @garyp This was my understanding till learning that those dark stripes are not there because the photons cancel each other out but they change their course to hit the bright regions making them brighter becase the probability of them interfering is higher because no one is watching them

Comment: Yes the all the photons go to the bright areas, none to the dark.  Another way to understand it is that photons must (with high probability) travel a distance a multiple of their wavelength, thus bright ares are ideal paths and dark areas not.  Feynman did work in this area considering all paths but eventually choosing the shortest that was n times wavelength.

Comment: @PhysicsDave What about a photon in a superposition of either hitting the barrier or pass through the right slit but not the left one? would it also with high probability hit the wal in a bright spot?

Comment: @AmrBerag  There are many classical but some what out of date explanations for 2 slit interference. You can google single photon (or electron) 2 slit interference, experiments that happened in the 1960s.  Photons that hit the barrier never get to the screen, all photons getting thru the barrier make the bright spots.

Comment: The photons do not change course.  There are two ways to look at this.  One is the way optical physicist look at it, the other is the way high-energy physicists look at it.  They are rather different pictures.  I wrote an answer on this.  I'll see if I can find it.

Comment: @garyp Yes they dont change course but they behave like a wave when there is no observer or "hypothetical detector " but what if  we remove the gap between the slits so that we have one wider slit or made a horizintal slit in the middle so that its an H shaped. if you ask someone who don't know about the experiment he/she will think the pattern is result of  light refraction in the air and passing the slits at different angels like soccer players shadows as a result of multiple light sources, which is wrong.

Comment: @garyp Im not asking about the abive but about wheter the shadow of the gap has enything  to do with the dark regions in other words if we remove the gab will we still get somehow a related patern because of diffraction at the far edges and a bright region in the midle opposite  to the wide slit given that the gap and slits are made as wider as possible before removing the gap? I hop you get what i mean. sorry for my bad english and  vocabulary problems and I have to write too much to explain